# The only page I see in my Django project is "migrations." I'm new to Django and the command line and am trying to create a "Hello World" page

Tags: django, python-3.x, command-line, windows-10

I'm totally new to Django and the command line.. so please bear with me :)

I started a Django project in virtualenv - but the "tree" doesn't show much at all. According to the tutorial I'm using (https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/), after typing

```
$ django-admin startproject helloworld_project .
```

and entering

```
$ tree
```

I should have seen:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── helloworld_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

However, I only got:

```
C:.
└── helloworld_project
```

I see these files in the directory when I open the folder with the Windows explorer, though. How do I see the whole tree?

I'm trying to create a "Hello World" page in Django using this tutorial:
https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/ ...

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Django.

The tutorial is clearly written for Mac users (by the mention of homebrew). You're using Windows (as we can see because of the "C:" entry in your tree). The `tree` command differs between those platforms; on Unix-like platforms such as Mac, it shows the files in all folders by default, but on Windows, you need to use the `/f` flag. So:

```
tree /f
```